# Simple Auth method leads to "Maximum update depth exceeded"

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I wanted to create a simple authentication using react and firebase. So my code is fairly simple. I use the firebase auth to create an user (works like a charm) and also to get the user (works like a charm). Then I save the corresponding token in the sessionStorage.
Now it gets tricky: I just want to call this token to check, if the user has permission to access a page. So my code looks like this:

```
    function InternCheckPage() {

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() =>{
        let authToken = sessionStorage.getItem('auth_token')

        if(authToken){
            navigate('/intern')
        }
        if(!authToken){
            navigate('/login')
        }

    })

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="App-header">
                <p>
                    InternCheck
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default InternCheckPage;
```

However, this leads to the following error:

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a
> component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either
> doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on
> every render.

and my page stops to respond. Frankly I dont know what I did wrong. I just took this code snipped from a tutorial where it's supposed to work just fine.

Any advice?

Comment: İnitialise the `let authToken = sessionStorage.getItem('auth_token') || 'some state'` outside the useEffect

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesnt make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really use `useEffect` without a dependency array, I think that in this case a simple empty array as the second argument to useEffect would do the trick for you.

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...code
}, [])
```

meaning code runs only the first time the component gets rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that I've used that might be helpful. Rather than manage storing and retrieving the authenticated user yourself, you could delegate that work to the `onAuthStateChanged` function that the firebase SDK provides.

What you see below is a custom hook that is responsible for returning the authenticated user.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, User } from '@firebase/auth';

import { app } from '../../configuration/FirebaseConfiguration';

const useAuth = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const auth = getAuth(app);

  let mounted = useRef<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    mounted.current = true;
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      console.log("onAuthUserChanged", user);
      if (user) {
        if (mounted.current) {
          setUser(user);
        }
      } else {
        if (mounted.current) {
          setUser(null);
        }
      }
    });

    return () => {
      mounted.current = false;
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [auth]);

  return {
    user,
    auth,
  };
};

export { useAuth };
```

You can call it as so in any other component

```
 const { user } = useAuth();
```

And, here's the github repository I created that uses this approach https://github.com/SangeetAgarwal/FirebaseAuthReactRouterv6

Here's link to resource I found very helpful when I was learning firebase authentication https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup.

So, now with the custom authentication hook above, your specific code would look something like this

```
function InternCheckPage() {

    let navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const { user } = useAuth();

    useEffect(() => {
        // let authToken = sessionStorage.getItem('auth_token')

        if (user) {
            navigate('/intern')
        } else {
            navigate('/login')
        }
        //if(!authToken){
        //    navigate('/login')
        //}

    }, [user])

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="App-header">
                <p>
                    InternCheck
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default InternCheckPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Test_1() {
let navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
let authToken = sessionStorage.getItem('auth_token');

if (authToken) {
  navigate('/intern');
} else {
  navigate('/login');
}
}, []);

return (
<div className='App'>
  <div className='App-header'>
    <p>InternCheck</p>
  </div>
</div>
);
}
```

I changed your code a bit due to fix the bug. This would hopefully work now.